# window.removeEventListener not working on componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

This is my code, using in component, but when i route to another URL the console gives me error -

ERROR

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
> componentWillUnmount method.

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
   // await myAPI call
   window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onWindowscroll);
  }

  onWindowscroll = async () => {
    console.log('onWindowscroll);
    // await myAPI call when scroll reach to bottom.
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onWindowscroll);
    console.log('componentWillUnmount H');
  }
```

Don't know why this is coming! This ERROR comes when I hard refresh and go to any other route.

As I am using arrow functions so I don't need `.bind` to be used in mounting time.

Comment: Are you doing any state update inside `onWindowscroll` function?

Comment: Yes @Siddharth but only in one case when my scroll reaches to bottom of page. otherwise not and the error is coming before that, if i don't reaches the bottom and go somewhere else in application.

Comment: you cannot call lifecycle method like arrow function.`async componentDidMount () { }`